# Custom user control with repeating data

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeat, webusercontrol

Below is code that I'm aiming for.  I need a custom user control that can be data bound to, but also contain other content (so just a raw repeater wont suffice).  The end goal is something along the lines of:

```
<MyControls:Control1 runat="server" id="Control1">
    <headertemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Username</td>
        </tr>
    </headertemplate>
    <itemtemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#((User)Container.DataItem).ID %></td>
            <td><%#((User)Container.DataItem).Username %></td>
        </tr>
    </itemtemplate>
</MyControls>
```

And:

```
var users = GetUsersList();
Control1.DataSource = users;
Control1.DataBind();
```

And looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.MyControl1" %>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Wrapper">

    <h2>Results</h2>

    <table>
        <%=HeaderTemplate%>
        <%
            if(ItemTemplate.AnyItems()){
                foreach(var item in ItemTemplate){

                }
            }
            else
            {
            %>Nothing here<%
            }
        %>
    </table>
    <MyControls:AnotherControl runat="server" />

</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I've found a page on ScottGu's Blog that appears to show what I want:
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Supporting-Templates-with-ASP.NET-User-Controls

But the linked to tutorial 404's now!  All other examples I've found don't seem to be well written and very hard to pick apart.

Any help on how to achieve the above would be much appreciated.

Comment: What linked tutorial can't you find?

Comment: On ScottGu, links to http://90statehouse.com/forums/blogs/robertseder/archive/2006/06/04/201.aspx

Comment: Try this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20060708013314/http://90statehouse.com/forums/blogs/robertseder/archive/2006/06/04/201.aspx)

Comment: @Pikoh excellent, that works great!  Only problem is I'm unable to modify it so that one of the templates can be bindable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting 2 different Controls mixed up. `UserControl` and `Repeater` (I think).

To bind data in to a Control inside a UserControl, you need to make that Control accessible from the parent. You can do this by creating a public property inside the UserControl.

```
public Repeater myRepeater
{
    get
    {
        return Repeater1;
    }
    set
    {
        Repeater1 = value;
    }
}
```

UserControl ascx with the Repeater Control

```
<table border="1">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Username</td>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("ID") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("Username") %></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Now you have access to `Repeater1` in the parent due to the public property.

```
Control1.myRepeater.DataSource = users;
Control1.myRepeater.DataBind();
```

And leave the control on the aspx parent empty.

```
<MyControls:Control1 runat="server" id="Control1"></MyControls>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, making a repeater inside the control that's publically accessible is one solution but I'm trying to contain it all within the control itself.

Comment: Don't make the repeater publicly accessible, write some forwarding/proxy methods & properties in your usercontrol for accessing the repeater. More effort than making the repeater public yes, but gives you control over how the repeater is accessed.

Comment: @Tom, containing everything in the control is usually how it's done. But since you wrote `Control1.DataSource = users;` it looked like you wanted to access the Repeater from the parent. If not you can just use `myRepeater.DataSource = users;` in the control itself.